# asp.net hyperlink navigateurl keeps hostname

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

Hope you can help - I have dynamic Hyperlink created during runtime, which is populated from the SQL.

When I click on the link it opens the hostname:port/weblink.

I'm sure this is quick fix, but I can't find it.

Thanks

```
        HyperLink BookmarkLink = new HyperLink
        {
            Text = BokName,
            NavigateUrl = BokUrl,
            Target = "_blank"
        };
```

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue here, but usually, the hostname is kept when the URL like this `/section/page` and not the fully qualified URL like `https://example.com/section/page`

Comment: I just found the issue - Yes, it needs to have https:// in the section. Thanks